# Vue Overlay for specific card

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using Vue with Vuetify and I used a for loop to render 8 different cards. Each card has its own overlay which shows its own image when clicked, however when I click one card, all of the overlays get set off instead of the overlay for just the specific card. How should I go about doing this? Would I have to add an ID for each card?

```js
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    arts: [
      require("@/assets/art1.jpg"),
      require("@/assets/art2.jpg"),
      require("@/assets/art3.jpg"),
      require("@/assets/art4.jpeg"),
      require("@/assets/art5.jpg"),
      require("@/assets/art6.jpg"),
      require("@/assets/art7.jpg"),
      require("@/assets/art8.jpg")
    ],
    absolute: true,
    opacity: 1,
    overlay: false,
  })
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <v-container fluid style="height:100%; background-color:#fc8276; width:25%; float:left"></v-container>
    <v-container style=" height: 100%; width: 75%; float:right" fluid>
      <h1>Portfolio</h1>
      <v-card
        v-for="art in arts"
        class="ma-5"
        v-bind:key="art"
        style="width: 15em; height: 15em; display:inline-flex"
      >
        <v-img :src="art" v-on:click="overlay=true"></v-img>
        <v-overlay :absolute="absolute" :opacity="opacity" :value="overlay">
            {{art}}
        </v-overlay>
      </v-card>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but something like this should work... basically restructure your data a bit. Right now you have **one** `overlay` data boolean. Whenever you are setting this to `true`, you are setting it to `true` for **everything** that is using that same boolean... in your case all of your overlayables are looking at that same boolean.

Also I would recommend moving your styles into CSS classes, it will make this way more readable...

You need to update your HTML to this:

```
<template>
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <v-container fluid style="height:100%; background-color:#fc8276; width:25%; float:left"></v-container>
    <v-container style=" height: 100%; width: 75%; float:right" fluid>
      <h1>Portfolio</h1>
      <v-card
        v-for="(art, index) in arts"
        class="ma-5"
        v-bind:key="index"
        style="width: 15em; height: 15em; display:inline-flex"
      >
        <v-img :src="art" v-on:click="showOverlay(art, index)"></v-img>
        <v-overlay :absolute="absolute" :opacity="opacity" :value="art.overlay">
            {{art.asset}}
        </v-overlay>
      </v-card>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then change your data a bit:

```
data: () => ({
    arts: [
      { asset: require("@/assets/art1.jpg"), overlay: false },
      { asset: require("@/assets/art2.jpg"), overlay: false },
      { asset: require("@/assets/art3.jpg"), overlay: false },
      { asset: require("@/assets/art4.jpeg"), overlay: false },
      { asset: require("@/assets/art5.jpg"), overlay: false },
      { asset: require("@/assets/art6.jpg"), overlay: false },
      { asset: require("@/assets/art7.jpg"), overlay: false },
      { asset: require("@/assets/art8.jpg"), overlay: false }
    ],
    absolute: true,
    opacity: 1,
  })
```

Then in your `methods`:

```
methods: {
  showOverlay(art, index) {
    this.arts.map((a) => a.overlay = false);
    this.arts[index].overlay = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked thanks! I dont understand the this.arts.map((a) => a.overlay = false); bit. What does map do? If you dont mind explaining

Comment: Great to hear, `map` basically loops over the array and allows you to set a value... I am doing this because we want to set all the other overlays to `false` before we toggle the clicked one. You can play around with it more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

I would make a new component which holds the v-card, so each one would have its own overlay data property. But having it all in one component with arts.length overlay variables works as well